# How check a users name when accessing a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

Hi guys ive spent the last 3 hours trying to get this work so any help would be greatly appreciated. So i made an express webapp that has an admin page. I have the register and login done using passport and i can check if the user is logged in with the function

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
// if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
// Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
// request and response objects
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
// if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
res.redirect('/');}
```

I when i click on the link for my admin route i want to check to see if the users username is equal to example and if it is allow it into the page. My code so far is

```
  var isAdmin = function (req, res, next) {


    if (req.session.username === 'example') {

    return next();
  }else{
  // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

and my route is

```
router.get('/admin', isAdmin, function(req, res){
    res.render('admin', { title : 'admin' });
});
```

I have both of these code snipets in my index route file. The problem that i am getting is that when i try to log in with the user called example it returns me to the login page. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: your variable name is post.. are you trying to catch a post when sending a get?

Comment: no i just randomly named the variable post

Comment: ok, well first thing your variable names should explain your code so if someone else saw it they could understand it (just for future reference helps people like us when we see it) :).. secondly, did you try printing out what req.body.username is? also you should check to see if req.body exists too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as long as you have the session package installed. You will also need the body parser package installed.

```
router.get('/admin', function(req, res){
    if (req.session.passport.user === undefined || req.session.passport.user !== 'example') {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else{
        res.render('admin', {title: 'admin'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes got it working i switched it over to my app.js and edit it too         app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
    if (req.user.username === undefined || req.user.username !== 'example') {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else{
        res.render('admin', {title: 'admin'});
    }
}); god bless you kind programmer

Answer (score 0):

I got it working :)

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
if (req.user.username === undefined || req.user.username !== 'example') {
    res.redirect('/');
} else{
    res.render('admin', {title: 'admin'});
}
 });
```